# iframe loads style of the parent page. Is here any way to specify the domain?

Tags: php, css, iframe

I am developing a HTML mobile browser simulator. For this I have used curl method for parsing the actual website content that is to be tested. This I loaded in the iframe in my website.
The iframe src will looklike mydomain.com/tester.php?url=urltobetested.com
where tester.php resides in my domain and parses the test url content as html string.
My problem is that, the iframe also loads the styles that I used in my domain, so the actual styles of test url was missing.

Is there any way to specify the url within the html content something like ?

thanks in advance